# How to reset using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a project using bootstrap ui ?(AngularJS). I want to implement a reset function to reset all the input fields and radio buttons. I've tried to add a new controller in my JS file, but failed. The following is my code.
Html part:

```
 <div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">

        <table class="table">

            {% verbatim %}

            <tr>
                <td class="input-group" ng-repeat="(k,v) in alerts">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Check {{ k }}</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Check here">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <b>functional check</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="a1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <b>CFM issue</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="a1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <b>Defect risk</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="a1">

                </td></tr>
            {% endverbatim %}
            <tr><td><button type="button" class='btn btn-info' ng-click="addAlert()">+Add Check</button>
                <button type="reset" ng-click="reset()" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
            </td></tr></table></div>
```

and my JS:

```
{{ ngapp }}.controller("AlertDemoCtrl", function ($scope, $http){

$scope.alerts = [];

$scope.addAlert = function() {
$scope.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!'});
};

$scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
$scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
};
$scope.reset = function() {
$scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
};

$scope.reset();

});
```

Can some one suggest me a way to make it happen.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could develop your model a bit more to include a list of properties for each alert:

```
$scope.addAlert = function() {
    $scope.alerts.push({
      msg: 'Another alert!',
      props: 0,
      input: ""
    });
  };
```

tie the view to those properties:

```
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Check here" ng-model="v.input">
        <br/>
        <b>functional check</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" value="fc" ng-model="v.props">
        <br/>
        <b>CFM issue</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" value="cfm" ng-model="v.props">
        <br/>
        <b>Defect risk</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" value="dr" ng-model="v.props">
```

and then iterate over each alert's properties during the reset:

```
$scope.reset = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.alerts, function(v) {
      v.input = "";
      v.props = 0;
    });
  };
```

please refer to this plunker I created for you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JINIgCOTfD2c5dklldQc?p=preview

**update:**

to hide an element use ng-hide attribute. I updated the plunkr

Comment: That's great Aex. It worked. Can I use this opportunity to ask you, what if I want to delete each dynamic added row (input filed and radio buttons) individually how can I do that?

Comment: Thanks Alex. You're so supportive!

Comment: Hi Alex, ng-hide is actually hiding the field right? Lets say if u add a variable in each input filed (Lets say you added a new input the value change from 1 to 2, and if you delete(here its ng-hide) the 2 and add input 3, now the page will displaying and input 1 and input 3, by "hiding" the input 2 other than deleting it. How can we actually delete it?